# Python take screenshot and display image in html tag

Tags: python, html, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying show a screenshot .png, take it with my python script in the browser. But i don't know why but i can't see the image!

Script Located at /var/www/cgi-bin/web.py

```
from selenium import webdriver

self.driver = webdriver.Phantomjs()

self.driver.get("http://www.google.com")


try:
    # print "Take a picture"
    picture = (''.join(random.choice(string.letters + string.digits) for n in xrange(10)))
    self.driver.save_screenshot((picture) + '.png')
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print "<html>"
    print "<head>"
    print "<title>%s</title>" % self.driver.title
    print "</head>"
    print "<body>"
    print "<h2>ScreenShot: %s.png</h2>" % (picture)
    print "<img src='%s.png'>" % (picture)
    print "</body>"
    print "</html>"
except IOError:
    print "Error take a picture!"
    pass
```

But a can't show the image on my browser the message error is:

```
(13)Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/fBgshhFbuJ.png'
```

What's wrong with my script?

---

Let me explain a little more what i trying do.
I've a form html what a send two strings to my python script and it take a screenshot, in the /var/www/cgi-bin folder. I wish to display the png file in a container or div html but inside the another html file specifically.

So is it possible?

I change the permission of folder /var and others subfolder, but i recieve the same error message.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds simple to me - the user it's running as doesn't have permissions. That is, what permission denied usually means, right?

Comment: @Arran you right, but the user of trying open the file is apache and i change the group permission to apache with 775 recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to write in the folder `/var/www/cgi-bin/` probably more specifically the `/var/` folder. If you change your script location to somewhere that you can have permission to write to, or the download location of your picture, then your program should work fine.

**Edit**

if you delete `IOError` from your except, you should be able to print the message and pass the error

Comment: @RodrigoAndrade let me know your results

Comment: I remove the IOError statement and same message error.

Comment: So your except statement is just `except:` instead of `except IOError:` and it doesn't print whats inside?

Comment: Let me explain a little more what i trying do, ok?
I have form html with two fields e-mail and url that a send to my python script, works fine. After access the url a take a screenshot with sucessfuly, but a can't display the image on browser via cgi, but i have permission to write in the folder /var/www/cgi-bin.

Is it possible i pass via parameter the localization of my image file to another html file and input into a div?

Thanks

Comment: thank you for help me, the problem was simple i just change the location of file to /var/www/html/images and finished. The image is displayed.